# Python - PyDev and Eclipse Juno - not working Console

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I have just installed PyDev plugin in Eclipse Juno but really don't have a clue how to get output after I start the script.There is a standard Eclipse Console, but it doesn't show script output, only this every time after I start the script.

```
Finding files... done.
Importing test modules ... done.

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

I don't see any other Console that I can add...suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are running the script as 'Python unit-test', and there are no tests. Maybe you need to use 'Python run'.

Comment: thanks! seems that was the case, but I'm confused now.Eclipse won't use python run configuration that I created, it always use python unittest when I click run button, and If I want python run I need every time to select it manually.I also tried to delete unittest configuration, but it is again automatically created, so I don't know really what to do about that.

Comment: Not sure. For me it uses 'Python run' all the time, after I select it once.

Comment: Nevermind, I removed 'unittest' from Run/Debug Launch configuration settings and now python run is an only option and default.Thanks.

Comment: Note: the best way to run a process in pydev is just using 'F9'.